# Code-behind file, how can I use it with using "imports" ? -Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio

Currently I have this main file: `form1` and I've created one code-behind file called `globalFunctions`... but now I need to know how to connect the two files. I guess I need to use 'import' in somewhere...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, especially [ask], before posting your next question here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To edit a code-behind file in a WinForm project, you can double-click the file name under Files in the Project panel.

Just click the `Form1` in the right sidebar and you will enter the code edit panel.

[The Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoTZX.jpg)